# Change the Display Name of my Thunderbolt A 1407 Display

Tags: thunderbolt-display

I am using an antique Mac Pro from 3013 running 12.6.2.

Is there a way to change the Display name from the defaults:  Display 1, Display 2 etc, other than modifying code that I have seen in other posts?

Comment: Display names should be the make & model of the display. eg https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9ElC.png - two almost but not quite identical displays attached.

Comment: What code have you seen?